# DVD drive is not able to detect or read blank dvd

Tags: dvd, optical-drive, dvd-burning

I have a TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L632H DVD drive in my laptop. This drive is not able to detect or read blank dvd of Moser Baer but it can read blank dvd of Sony.

What is the problem ?

What is the solution ?

Comment: It could be your drive has become dusty. Especially in laptop drives this happens a lot. It might be possible to get the dust out with compressed air. This fixed similar issues on a slot-in drive of mine which wasn't able to read any DVD at all (CDs working fine though).

Answer (score 1):

CD/DVD drives have a list of compatible media hard coded into the firmware of the device, its possible this media type is not in the list, so it cannot identify it, a firmware update would solve this if they added this particular type to the list.

Otherwise you would need to replace the DVD drive with a newer model.